# Just a thought on Apache Distinguish Traffic

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

Is there a way to distinguish between traffic from apps server and web server for Apache. I mean webs maybe down but if the traffic coming from other server there will be 200 code traffic and hard to redirect. Or vice versa...

Comment: I think you need to improve your question. Its really hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: Well I mean like. Lets say you have Tom cat as apps server and a webserver. You have web server down but when you hit www.something.com the apps server will return the code of 200. Now Apache is confused and not gonna redirect to brokenpage.html because 200 code from apps is overlaying the return code from web server.

Comment: If you redirect from Apache WS to Tomcat (modjk/modproxy) than you gonna get a "Unable to connect" message. If Tomcat is shut down while the WS is running you will get a 500 status.

Comment: hmm...what if webserver is down but apps is up. I get 200 from apps and apache is not taking to redirect page even Jboss is down. If I recall 503 from JBoss. I get 200 from apps and 503 from apache and no redirect page. Maybe there is a way to check the heartbeat?